# Is something infecting my Google searches?

Tags: google-chrome, malware, spyware, google-search

I starting doing some experimentation toward making a browser userscript for Google searches and when opening the JavaScript console noticed something that strikes me as very fishy:

```
The page at https://www.google.com.au/search?oq=XYZ&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=XYZ displayed insecure content from http://50.116.62.47/js/chromeServerV45.js.
The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from http://96.126.107.154/amz/google.php?callback=a&q=XYZ&country=US.
```

(XYZ is a placeholder for whatever the search terms really was.)

Is it likely that I've picked something like a drive-by browser infection? I've tried all kinds of searches for these URLs and other keywords but I've had no luck finding anything conclusive about whether they're malicious or what they are:

- `50.116.62.47`
- `chromeServerV45.js`
- `96.126.107.154`
- `amz/google.php`

The only extensions I have installed are either widely used or written by myself. But something else is strange and I'm not sure if it's just a coincidence. I updated my Windows Chrome browser today to version 23.0.1271.64 m and now my Extensions tab as well as my settings tab are blank, so I can't try disabling my extesions.

---

Here's some discussion I've been able to find so far but not really understand and make sense of:

- for `96.126.107.154` : ["anomalous-javascript-pt2"](http://pythorian.wordpress.com/2012/01/21/anomalous-javascript-pt2/)

Comment: Did you try running a malware scan with MalwareBytes or the like?

Comment: @BrenBarn: Spyboy Search & Destroy found only one DoubleClick cookie. Malwarebytes found nothing at all on its quick search and has now doing a full search for 1 hour 45 minutes without finding anything yet ...

Comment: I went to `50.116.62.47` and it redirected me to `localhost`. I would guess the content is being served up from your computer? Take a look at open ports, is there anything on 80?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Yes I remember seeing the same. I'm running Windows 7 Starter and I'm a big vague on how to check for open ports...

Comment: @BrenBarn: Malwarebytes has now completed. It found one thing only, called "PUP.HiddenStart.H" which was in xyz`\Downloads\software (other)\hstart.exe`. Now when I use Gmail or Google Search in Google Chrome I still get one warning but so far not the other. This one remains: `http://66.228.34.50/js/chromeServerV45.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My extensions tab began working again and I've been able to go through the extensions one by one after running Spybot Search & Destroy and Malwarebytes.

I've discovered the source of **`50.116.62.47/js/chromeServerV45.js`** was:

> YouTube Downloader: MP3 / HD Video Download 13.0
>   Download any video from YouTube as an MP3 or an HD Video. Adds a download button to YouTube video pages. [Visit website](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jkkeahicimadnjhdamcladhobabaafbg)
>   ID: jkkeahicimadnjhdamcladhobabaafbg

I had installed it because it was an officially supported extension made by YouTube, which of course means made by Google. I notice it's no longer in the Chrome Web Store.